# Is it possible to limit the args of a ParamArray in a VBA Class Sub or Property?

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, parameters

I'm creating a vba excel class and are trying to figure out how to allow users to set groups of values that apply to a variable/field. From what I've read, it's not possible to have multiple parameters on a Property unless you intend for them to be required. What'd I'm trying to do is make it so only the first parameter is required the and a remaining number of parameters is optional. I've seem the suggestion of using a sub when needing to make subsequent parameters optional. That works fine, for example, when I'm setting up the following Sub

```
Public Sub SetCategories(CategoryOne As String, Optional CategoryTwo As String)
    pCategories(0) = CategoryOne
    pCategories(1) = CategoryTwo
End Sub
```

Since there are only two parameters and I need only one to be required the above setup suffices. However, I have other properties that I need to allow up to 30 values and I'd really rather not hardcode 1 required value and 29 optional because that just seems like bad design. That's when I started looking into the ParamArray option. The ParamArray is perfect for this situation, except there's one issue I'm running into. The ParamArray allows as many args as you want and I need to be able to limit it to 29 (plus the one required). So, is there a way to limit the upperbound of a ParamArray to only allow so many arguments for a Sub?

Something like the following

```
Public Sub SetKeywords(KeywordOne As String, Optional ParamArray KeywordTwoThroughThirty(29) as String)

End Sub
```

Is that possible? If so, how? If not, how would you suggest I go about this scenerio?

Comment: *it's not possible to have multiple parameters on a Property unless you intend for them to be required* - IMO using property parameters for anything other than to create an *indexed property* is language abuse. Good decision making it a method.

Comment: 30 optional parameters is a bad design? Please tell whoever wrote `Application.Run`! =)

Comment: Nice to see you again @Mat'sMug :) it's been awhile since I've needed assistance. So, how do you think I should handle the situation to provide up to 30 slots? I'd like it to display like how other parameters display on functions when they're optional. Example when typing `test.SetKeywords(` I'd like it to look something like `KeywordOne As String, [KeywordTwoThroughThirty2],[KeywordTwoThroughThirty3]...[KeywordTwoThroughThirty30])`. Is that at all possible? If not, is there another method you'd suggest for providing the 30 optional params?

Comment: If you want that kind of IntelliSense then you need to do what `Application.Run` did - that's right, 30 explicitly optional parameters. And then live with callers being able to do `DoSomething "foo", arg10:="bar"` to supply one optional argument and break everything that expected the first optional argument to be `arg1` ;-)

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder - Who are your users? Could you expect them to be able to pass an array, then your function could use only the non empty elements?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not completely following what you mean @Mat'sMug :P Do you mind providing an example as an answer to help my rustiness along ;)

Comment: @Absinthe I have to assume my users are complete imbeciles; therefore, I need it to be straight-forward. Most, if not all, would have no idea how to correctly pass an array unfortunately. That's why I'd like to be able to provide an Intellisense-like experience for them.

Comment: You're not *passing an array* with `ParamArray` - you're passing a comma-separated list of parameters, and VBA stuffs them into an array for you.

Comment: @CaffeinatedCoder - Assuming untrained monkeys will be using your code how about a low-tech solution? Create a worksheet & table to hold the parameters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible. `ParamArray`, as the name states, gives you a *parameter array*.

A `ParamArray` can only be passed by reference (implicitly - explicit `ByRef` won't compile), and only be an array of `Variant` items, and can't be `Optional` - so this can't compile:

```
Optional ParamArray KeywordTwoThroughThirty(29) as String
```

Instead you'd just do:

```
ParamArray KeywordTwoThroughThirty()
```

What you *can* do, is use a *guard clause* to throw an error back at the caller when they've supplied too many arguments - interestingly it seems `Option Base` has no impact on the base boundary of `ParamArray` arrays, which seems to be 0 regardless of `Option Base` settings.. which makes it much simpler to verify how many arguments were specified:

```
Const maxArgs As Long = 30
If UBound(KeywordTwoThroughThirty) + 1 > maxArgs Then
    Err.Raise 5, "SetKeywords", _
                 "Too many arguments were specified. Maximum is " & maxArgs & "."
End If
```

Now the callers can pass up to 30 optional arguments; if they pass 31 or more, they'll have to deal with a run-time error 5 "invalid procedure call or argument", which is particularly appropriate here.

---

*IntelliSense* won't help your callers know how many arguments they're passing though:

[image: IntelliSense showing only one argument]

If you want calling code's *IntelliSense* to look like this:

[image: IntelliSense showing all arguments, optional ones in square brackets]

...then you need to specify explicit optional arguments *for every single one of the 30 arguments you can get*.

That's how `Application.Run` did it.

[image: Application.Run intellisense]

I'd recommend passing them all explicitly `ByVal` though.

One problem you can hit is that a clever caller can do this:

```
DoSomething arg1:="foo", arg14:="bar"
```

And now if your implementation assumes an empty `arg2` means an empty `arg3` and an empty `arg14`, then you'll have bugs... whereas the `ParamArray` solution doesn't quite allow the user to mess things up with named arguments, and your implementation can iterate the array if it needs to, depending on the purpose of this.

---

I'd recommend a different approach though.

> ```
> Public Sub SetCategories(CategoryOne As String, Optional CategoryTwo As String)
>     pCategories(0) = CategoryOne
>     pCategories(1) = CategoryTwo
> End Sub
> ```

Your class won't have a value for `pCategories(0)` if the caller doesn't call `SetCategories` anyway - so I'd go with your first idea: an indexed property:

```
Public Property Get Category(ByVal index As Long) As String
    Category = pCategories(index)
End Property

Public Property Let Category(ByVal index As Long, ByVal value As String)
    pCategories(index) = value
End Property
```

And then expose some `Init` method:

```
Public Sub Init(ByVal category1 As String)
    ReDim pCategories(0 To 29) As String
    pCategories(0) = category1
End Sub
```

That way the caller can do this:

```
With foo
    .Init "bar"
    .Category(1) = "smurf"
    .Category(2) = "blah"
    '...
End With
```

And they can work with loops and other data structures to access and manipulate the 30 encapsulated items; VBA will take care of throwing a *subscript out of range* error if they try to work with more than 30 elements.

Comment: Really clever with the alternate approach and as always a very well-explained approach. Much appreciated, thank you :)